# double integral of f zero over subsets of $[0,1]^2$ implies $f=0$ almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, product-measure

Here's the statement of the problem:

*Let $f \in L^1([0,1]^2,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{[0,1]^2}),m)$, where $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{[0,1]^2})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $m$ is the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Prove that if $\int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{b}f(x,y)dydx = 0$ for all $a, b \in  [0,1]$, then $f=0$ $m$-a.e.*

So the idea of the proof is to let $\mathscr{C}=\{E\subset[0,1]^2: \int_{E}f dm=0\}$ and show that $\mathscr{C}$ contains all sets that are the product of two intervals and that it is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then it contains the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. This gives the desired result by Prop 8.1 in the Bass Real Analysis book.

My question is in showing $\mathscr{C}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. I've done everything but show it is closed under countable unions... I've tried taking a collection of sets in $\mathscr{C}$ and breaking them into a disjoint collection with the same union but then can't confidently prove that this integral is zero.

Could someone help?

Comment: If integral if $f$ is zero on two sets $A, B$ it does not follow the integral is zero on $A \cap B$.

Comment: @GEdgar Right!! That is the issue I'm trying to get around.. any ideas on how?

Comment: Just note that the sets of the form you are integrating over form a $\pi$-system. A standard result says that if two finite measures agree on a $\pi$-system, then they are equal.

Comment: Abandon this argument. The result is clear, for example  from the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea seems plausible, I suspect it needs the $\pi-\lambda$ Theorem.

But it seems that the reasoning goes through:

It is not hard to see that
\begin{align*}
\iint_{[a,b]\times[c,d]}f(x,y)dxdy=0,
\end{align*}
so the measure $\mu$ defined by
\begin{align*}
\mu([a,b]\times[c,d])=\iint_{[a,b]\times[c,d]}f(x,y)dxdy
\end{align*}
is actually the zero functional, and in fact it is the Radon-Nikodym of $f$, that is,
\begin{align*}
f=\dfrac{d\mu}{dm},~~~~\text{a.e.},
\end{align*}
then $f=0$ a.e. since $0$ can be a Radon-Nikodym and each pair of two Radon-Nikodym differs up to a.e. only.